# Insert query failing with ORA-00911: invalid character exception

Tags: java, sql, insert

I'm trying to insert data into table with below java code lines and it is failing with executeUpdate(sql) with below error:

```
String userName = "some value";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

String sql = "INSERT INTO `GenericUserPasswordRequest`(ID,USERNAME,USERDATE) VALUE ('101','"+userName+"', '"+dateFormat.format(date)+"')";
                                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:931)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1707)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1670)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:310)
        at com.nk.EmailFormController.handleFormSubmit(EmailFormController.java:198)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Way to set yourself up for SQL injection....

Comment: [`SYSDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)

Comment: ' "+dateFormat.format(date)+" ' use this format.

Comment: Please look into how to use prepared statements - as suggested by @Tobb, creating SQL queries using string interpolation is very, very insecure.

Comment: @Tobb Good hint, but keep in mind: he is a newbie. It might be more helpful to explain to him *why* he is making a mistake, and give one sentence of how to do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed one ' at the start of dateFormat

```
'101','"+userName+"', "+dateFormat.format(date)+"'

'101','"+userName+"', '"+dateFormat.format(date)+"'
```

Also string concatenation in sql is evil use the good old setParameter()

Answer (score 0):

You don't have correct syntax for `INSERT`, the number columns and values should match.

You have specified 5 columns, but in `VALUES` you have 3 values. Their numbers and sequence **MUST** match.

Comment: My bad updated correctly now there was typo with number of columns mismatch with values insert.  Also there was typo with missing  "+dateFormat.format(date)+"'  I have updated it to  '"+dateFormat.format(date)+"'